# Supported filesystems for Ubuntu touch

Tags: filesystem, phone, bq, aquaris

So I've got the new BQ Aquaris E4.5 with Ubuntu OS, and put in my SD card which is formatted on NTFS.

It's not surprising that my phone does not recognize anything on the card, and i think Ext4 might will be alright. Anyway, the question is simple, what are the supported filesystems on the Ubuntu OS, and which of them is recommended for my SD card?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it still ext4, even I can't find any official link of the supported file system or what is the default file system used.

But as workaround you can still use some commands like `mount`, `df -h -T` , `blkid` which shows you the filesystem used in your system.

So give it a try and check your card FS

Comment: @Tom Welcome friend